# How to create advanced subscriptions expression at Orion Context Broker NGSIv2?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

According to [official documentation of Orion Context Broker NGSIv2](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html#subscriptions) :

> You can include filtering expressions in conditions. For example, to
>   get notified not only if pressure changes, but if it changes within
>   the range 700-800. This is an advanced topic, see the "Subscriptions"
>   section in the [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/).

At NGSIv2 subscriptions there is no `notifyConditions` such as NGSIv1 , it was replaced by subject.condition object:

> `condition`: Condition to trigger notifications. This field is optional
>   and it may contain two properties, both optional:
>
> - `attrs`: array of attribute names
> - `expression`: an expression composed of `q`, `mq`, `georel`,
>     `geometry` and `coords` (see "List entities" operation above about this
>     field)

When we use `subject.condition.attrs`, it contains an array of attributes names,  these names define the "triggering attributes", i.e. attributes that upon creation/change due to entity creation or update trigger the notification.

But, for `subject.condition.expression` there is not example at official documentations.

Getting pieces of puzzle is possible to deduce :

- Is possible do combine `subject.condition.expression` and `subject.condition.attrs`. If I set and attribute different of expression,eg. attr foo with expression 'boo>10' what it will do ? Will this behave like an `OR` or `AND` ?
- Is possible to set multiple expressions.  Will this behave like an `OR` or `AND` ?

It would be nice to have some examples of these more complex subscriptions combining the different ways of delimiting the entities in the subscription.

**NOTE:** This question is related to Orion Version 1.7.0+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following example, from the [NGSIv2 Overview for Developers That Already Know NGSIv1](https://www.slideshare.net/fermingalan/ngsiv2-overview-for-developers-that-already-know-ngsiv1) presentation (slide 34 in the current version), could help to clarify.

> **Example**: subscribe to *speed* changes in  any entities of any type ending with Vehicle (such as RoadVehicle, AirVehicle, etc.) whenever *speed* is greater than 90 its *average* metadata is between 80 and 90 and the vehicle distance to Madrid city center is less than 100 km

Request:

```
POST /v2/subscriptions
...
{  
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
     {
        "idPattern": ".*",
        "typePattern": ".*Vehicle"
     },
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [ "speed"  ],
      "expression":  {
         "q": "speed>90",
         "mq": "speed.average==80..100",
         "georel": "near;maxDistance:100000",
         "geometry": "point",
         "coords": "40.418889,-3.691944"
      }
      }
    },
   ...
}
```

As this example illustrates, you can use different conditions (`q`, `mq`, geoquery, etc.) and they are interpreted in the AND sense. Morevoer, `q` and `mq` allow complex expressions interpreted also in the AND sense, such as:

```
"q": "speed>90;engine!=fail",
```

Note that `q` and `mq` when they appear in subscriptions `expression` follow the same rules than the ones when they appear in synchronous queries (i.e. `GET /v2/entities?q=...`). These rules are described in "Simple Query Language" section in the [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/).